# Var does not change after "if" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a simple switch in a form. It works only one way. What am I missing here that is preventing this code from working?

**HTML**

```
<div id="SlideJoinDiv" align="right" style="background-image: url(img/buttons/SchuifNederlandsBG.png">
<img width="87px" height="53px" src="img/buttons/SchuifjeKnop.png" id="SlideJoin" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#SlideJoinDiv').click(function () {
    var waardeStart = 'gast';
    var waardeType = $('#TypeAccount').attr('value');
    if (waardeType = waardeStart) {
      $('#SlideJoinDiv').attr('align', 'left');
      $('#TypeAccount').attr('value', 'artist');
    } else {
      $('#SlideJoinDiv').attr('align', 'right');
      $('#TypeAccount').attr('value', 'gast');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please make your code readable, i.e. use proper indentation.

Comment: In the `if` statement, "=" should be a "=="?

Comment: Incidentally, [JS Hint](http://www.jshint.com/) would've shown you the assignment/comparison mistake (and others). This doesn't imply a down-vote, just advice for future JavaScript problems. (And, just to be absolutely clear, the current down-vote is not mine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
waardeType = waardeStart
```

Should be:

```
waardeType == waardeStart
```

Right now you're assigning, you need to be comparing.

Comment: Also he has a syntax error. He doesn't close the `});` for the onDocReady

Comment: @jan: how are we expected to know what errors are copy-paste errors and what are actual syntax errors in the code? We can only, surely, respond to the *code we can see*, unless there's a linked demo with working code in it.

Comment: @DavidThomas if the asker claims the code compiles you are safe to assume any mismatched parentheses are due to copy-paste errors

Comment: @Jan: I can't possibly assume the asker knows anything about coding, for all we know he copy/pasted this snippet from a tutorial online somewhere...

Comment: @jan: while that may be true, we can still only respond to the code we're shown, and I prefer (regardless of pithy quotes and aphorisms) to avoid assumptions where possible. That is, of course, a subjective approach.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in `if`

```
if (waardeType = waardeStart){
```

should be:

```
if (waardeType == waardeStart){
```

Explanation: one equal sign (=) is assignment, two equal signs (==) are comparison.

Comment: For completeness: `==` compares with type conversion and `===` compares without type conversion and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (waardeType = waardeStart)
```

is wrong.

use

```
if (waardeType == waardeStart)
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be "==" instead of "="
Comparison vs Assignation

Also, small typos in you style definition for the background-image.

```
style="background-image: url('img/buttons/SchuifNederlandsBG.png');"
```

instead of

```
style="background-image: url(img/buttons/SchuifNederlandsBG.png"
```

Comment: You don't need the single quotes around the png file.